# How to make the cron expression configurable by placing it in XML file

Tags: java, xml, cron

Am using cron scheduler to execute a job after every minute. Later i need this interval to be configurable. Is there any way that i can read the cron settings from a XML file and feed it to the scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

Well, cron understand a certain format which is not XML. You could add a cron job which will:

1. convert xml to cron format
2. add itself to the cron
3. update cron schedule